# How to set a gradient fill for an XSLF shape created in an Apache POI presentations?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I need to create a rectangle with a horizontal or vertical gradient fill in a PowerPoint presentation I'm creating with the Apache POI API.

I'm using XSLFFreeformShape for the rectangle:

```
    XSLFGroupShape currentGroup = ...;
    XSLFFreeformShape ppShape = currentGroup.createFreeform();
    ppShape.setPath( ... );
```

Setting a single, flat color is easy:

```
    ppShape.setFillColor( myColor );
```

And there's a mechanism to *get* details of the gradient fill, via superclass method `XSLFSimpleShape.getFillStyle()`.

But there's no corresponding `setFillStyle()`, and I don't see any other easy public way to specify a gradient.

**Question**: Can I create a rectangle with a gradient, and if so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When defining the current API, I was mainly focused on giving the image renderer enough information and left out probably a lot of write access properties.

So currently you need to use the XmlObjects to set the gradient:

```
package org.apache.poi.xslf;

import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.sl.usermodel.ShapeType;
import org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XMLSlideShow;
import org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XSLFAutoShape;
import org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XSLFSlide;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main.CTGradientFillProperties;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main.CTGradientStop;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main.CTGradientStopList;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.presentationml.x2006.main.CTShape;

public class TestGradientFill {
    @Test
    public void fill() throws Exception {
        XMLSlideShow ppt = new XMLSlideShow();
        XSLFSlide sl = ppt.createSlide();
        XSLFAutoShape as = sl.createAutoShape();
        as.setShapeType(ShapeType.STAR_12);
        as.setAnchor(new Rectangle2D.Double(100, 100, 100, 100));
        CTShape cs = (CTShape)as.getXmlObject();
        CTGradientFillProperties gFill = cs.getSpPr().addNewGradFill();
        gFill.addNewLin().setAng(1800000);
        CTGradientStopList list = gFill.addNewGsLst();

        // set the start pos
        CTGradientStop stop = list.addNewGs();
        stop.setPos(0);
        stop.addNewSrgbClr().setVal(new byte[]{ (byte)0x94, (byte)0xbd, (byte)0x5e });

        // set the end pos (100000 = 100%)
        stop = list.addNewGs();
        stop.setPos(100000);
        stop.addNewSrgbClr().setVal(new byte[]{ 0,0,0 });

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("gradient.pptx");
        ppt.write(fos);
        fos.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the complete example! I'll give it a try.